# DataTable in C# - named rows

Tags: c#

Is it possible to give name for each row in `DataTable`? I would like to simply refer to the given cell in `DataTable` by typing

```
myDataTable.Rows["Row1"]["Column1"]
```

instead passing Row Index as int.

Comment: No, DataTable has not a native functionality for that. But in reality you should tell us why are you still using DataTables instead of some ORM capable to transform your raw data in objects. At that point it will be easy to create a Dictionary with some unique property used as the key

Comment: [Items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarowcollection.item?view=net-6.0#system-data-datarowcollection-item(system-int32)) have only an index.

Comment: Why did you want to give a name for each row, because I think that might be created for iterator so that might not need a string name for `DataRowCollection`

Comment: Define constant `const int Row1 = 1;` then use it `.Rows[Row1]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this, because rows are only indexed by their row index. Columns are indexed by their column index and column name. If you need to reference rows by a name, you must create your own index:

```cs
var rowNameToIndexMap = new Dictionary<string, int>();
var dataTable = new DataTable();
      
/* Index a row */
var row = dataTable.NewRow();
dataTable.Rows.Add(row);
var rowName = "first row";
rowNameToIndexMap.Add(rowName, dataTable.Rows.Count - 1);

/* Retrieve first row by its row name */
if (rowNameToIndexMap.TryGetValue(rowName, out int rowIndex))
{
  var firstRow = dataTable.Rows[rowIndex];
}
```